# POSTMAN Error 422 - Unprocessable Entity, with GitHub API. What is it and how do solve it?

Tags: http, github, postman

What is the meaning of this error code and how do I fix it?
I am trying to access the statuses of a repository found in my GitHub profile using Postman.

The link of my repo statuses was taken from the GitHub API and posted in Postman next to the POST address bar as seen on the screenshot below. Once I hit "Send", the resulting status was a **422 Unprocessable Entity**

[image]

[image]

Anyone familiar with Postman and GitHub, and GitHub API knows what does this mean and any ideas on how to bypass this error and get at least a success code instead?

Comment: Here a description of HTTP 422: https://httpstatuses.com/422. Its usually related to invalid instructions. Make sure you have this repo/user exists and has access/permission to create this status and that the ref for that SHA exists. https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/#create-a-status

Comment: How do I allow access/permission to create the status though? The instruction in the link is not giving me much info about that particular area

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem, and the root cause was that I was sending an outdated pull request event payload to the API. I had copied the webhook payload from the GitHub -> Hooks UI, which contained the PR number and the head commit SHA at that time. Then I made a new commit into the head branch of the PR, meaning that the head commit SHA of the PR was different than it was when I originally copied the event. Updating the SHA in the payload resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Content-type from text/plain to application/json  in the header fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those who falls in the same problem, you can either change PUT method to PUT, or try to change the Postman Body from "form-data" to "raw", then selected JSON for input.
that helped me.
Checkout those images

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veBW6.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KZR6.png)